# ¿Se puede subir una pagina web a Sharepoint Sites y visualizarla?

Tags: web, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Pues mi duda es si puedo subir una pagina web a Sharepoint Sites con un archivo index.html que lo acompañan archivos Json y Javascript y como podría hacerlo.

Hasta ahora conseguir ejecutar código HTML y CSS pero a la hora de introducir el código de mi pagina Sharepoint no me lo acepta. Me salta un mensaje de error advirtiéndome de que se han quitado algunos de mis formatos.

Muchas gracias a todos.

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que estas tratando de hacer es personalizar tu SharePoint entonces podes hacer lo siguiente:

SP no permite cargar los files JSON, para habilitar esta posibilidad tenes que ir a `Administración Central de SharePoint`  ahì le das a `administrar aplicación web`, luego en el menu dropdown seleccionas `tipos de file bloqueados`, en el modal que se abre remueves la extención JSON de la lista y le das al boton `ok`.

Ahora que tu SP te permite cargar los archivos JSON, cargas tus archivos JS , CSS y JSON en `SiteAssets`.

Ahora entras en zona de modifica de la lista que deseas personalizar y agregas la web part `script editor` que se encuentra en la carpeta "elemenos multimediales y contenido". 
(lamentablemente mi SP esta en italiano, pero para que te des una idea agrego igualmente la foto)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

una vez que agregaste el editor le das a `modificar fragmento`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en la modal que se te abre pegas tu HTML y naturalmente cambias las referencias de los files CSS , JS y JSON, tendrian que quedar algo asi: `href="/site/misitio/SiteAssets/css/miestilo.css"`

guardas los cambios de la modifica y listo ! ya tienes tu personalización!

si no quieres aportar esta personalización en tu lista, lo podes hacer en una pagina wiki, el procedimiento es el mismo !

si las queres hacer en los forms :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y el procedimiento sigue siendo el mismo.

ejemplo de personalización : 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

espero que te sea de ayuda!